# regular 7-gons problem

Tags: geometry

There are two regular 7-gons sharing one vertex. The other vertices of the first one (starting from the common vertex $A_0(B_0)$)  in (say) clockwise order are $A_1, A_2... A_6$. The other vertices of the second one in the same order (clockwise in our case) are $B_1...B_6$. Show that the lines $A_1B_1,A_2B_2...A_6B_6$ go through one point. There is a hint: What similarity transformation takes one 7-gon to the other?

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the minor blemish in the figure: one of the connecting lines was left too short, because the common point was not between the pair of vertices. Otherwise I hope the picture makes the question clearer.

Comment: Have you made any progress yourself?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. In particular, have you answered the question in the hint? And do you see a strategy to use the hint to solve your problem?

Comment: Can be proved using differential geometry for any $n$ including a circle ($n\rightarrow \infty$). In this limit case all lines are concurrent at the other intersection point of the two circles.But this may be  outside OP's interest.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen thanks, but did you delete your answer, because I can't see it now

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Narasimhan the common point of intersection of the seven lines connecting corresponding vertices of the two 7-gons is the other point of intersection of the circles, call them $\color{orange}C_1$ and $\color{blue}C_2$, circumscribing the 7-gons. This is not using the hint, so possibly useless to the OP.

That claim follows relatively easily from basic circle geometry.
Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively. Let $A$ and $P$ be the points where the two circles intersect, so $A$ is a common vertex of the two polygons.

[image]

Let $L$ be any line through $P$. Denote by $Q$ (resp. $R$) the intersection of $L$ and $C_1$ (resp. $L\cap C_2$). Let $\alpha$ be the central angle $\angle AO_1Q$ (think of this in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ and specify that $AO_1$ is the left ray of that angle and $QO_1$ the right ray.

Then the inscribed angle (of $C_1$) equals $\angle APQ=\alpha/2$. We then get the same angle between the ray $PR$ and the extension (beyond $P$) of the line segment $AP$. Therefore the inscribed angle (in $C_2$ now!) $\angle RPA=\pi-\alpha/2$. This means that the central angle 
$$
\angle RO_2A=2(\pi-\frac\alpha2)=2\pi-\alpha
$$
(here $A$ lies on the right ray, and $R$ on the left ray).
Consequently the central angle $\angle AO_2R=\alpha$ (with left and right reversed) as well.

Therefore we have proven:

> With the above notations and definitions (cf. figure above) we have equality of the central angles $\angle AO_1Q=\angle AO_2R$.

The OP's claim follows from this as follows. We let $Q$ run over the set of vertices of the $7$-gon circumscribed by $C_1$. This amounts to letting $\alpha=k (2\pi/7)$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5,6.$ The above result then tells us that the corresponding sequence of points $R$ are the vertices of the unique regular $7$-gon circumscribed by $C_2$ that has $A$ as one of its vertices.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully conversant with the English terminology of elementary geometry. Please enlighten me (or just edit), if you spot me using an incorrect term.

Comment: Do you really think you should have given a (basically) complete answer, given the total lack of effort of the OP?

Comment: @Rory: I have been having second thoughts about that myself, and I have been half expecting downvotes. My excuses are: 1) I wanted to help by adding that image, so continuing was natural. 2) I used the opportunity to teach myself the English terms for *central angle* and *inscribed angle*. The excuses are lame. As I don't frequent the geometry tag I also don't know quite what is expected from the asker of a question like this. The question sat here for may be 5 hours without votes to close, so other users may be equally undecided. I do see and appreciate your point

Comment: 4 weeks have now gone, and the question escaped unclosed. It is probably ok now to undelete the answer. I understand, if anyone disagrees, and downvotes/votes to close/delete.

Comment: Your reasoning and action seem fine to me.